# Adding e-commerce functionality and blog feature in local java application

Tags: java, eclipse, e-commerce, payment-gateway

I am a student working on college project. A newbie in web development.
I developed a local java application for book management system for a bookstore using JSP/Servlets in eclipse and tomcat server. It has registration screen, login screen etc. I have included session management.

Now, I am asked to include following features in the same project.

Requirement-
Add: a) E-commerce functionality to it (Online Store, Shopping Kart, Payment Gateway). You may integrate the open source code available easily.
b) Add a blog feature (again you may integrate available codes)

I am not sure how we can include these features in local application.
Could you please help?

Comment: [For your shopping cart part you can refer this link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165257/good-opensource-java-shopping-cart-frameworks-that-can-be-extended-to-use-lucene)
And for the blog part you can refer to framework [Scooter] (http://www.scooterframework.com/docs/blog.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got 3 architectural options to choose from:
1. integrate an open source library into your own server
2. run an open source server next to your Tomcat
3. use a hosted solution and integrate with it

(3) I'm not sure what are the exercise restrictions, but #3 is the easiest by far. You can use Shopify, Magento or even Wix to easily create a store. Wix also have blogs available. The integration should be as easy as adding a link from your JSP to that hosted solution.

(2) If that's not acceptable, you can run use an open source e-commerce/blog solution that you will run next to your Tomcat. OpenCart is the leading solution here.

(1) Now, if you really really need to integrate the source code into your own Tomcat, you're left with small libraries and code fragments available online. I must admit I recommend none of them as the headache of integrating them is usually greater than the good of using them.